# NetCore3 API not returning/serializing my data

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

I have the following controller:

```
[HttpGet("idfull/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAccountByIdFull(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await _accountFacade.GetAccountByIdAsync(id, full: true).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (response == null)
                    return NoContent();

                return Ok(response);
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException kEx)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```

The Facade layer:

```
public async Task<AccountViewModel> GetAccountByIdAsync(int accountId, bool full = false)
        {
            try
            {
                var unmappedResponse = await _accountService.GetAccountByIdAsync(accountId, full);
                var mappedResponse = _mapper.Map<AccountViewModel>(unmappedResponse);

                return mappedResponse;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

The service layer:

```
public async Task<Account> GetAccountByIdAsync(int accountId, bool full = false)
    {
        try
        {
            Account account;
            if (full)
            {
                account = await _repo.GetOneAsync<Account>(x => x.AccountId == accountId);

                account.Company = await _repo.GetOneAsync<Company>(filter: x => x.CompanyId == account.CompanyId, 
                    includes: source => source
                    .Include(c => c.CompanyTransferType)
                        .ThenInclude(ctt => ctt.PartnerCompanyAccountType)
                    .Include(c => c.CompanyTransferType).ThenInclude(ctt => ctt.TransferType)
                    .Include(c => c.CompanyEquipment).ThenInclude(ce => ce.Equipment)
                    .Include(c => c.CompanyAccountGroup)
                    .Include(c => c.CompanyAccountType));

                account.AccountContact = await _repo.GetAsync<AccountContact>(filter: x => x.AccountId == accountId);

                account.AccountEquipment = await _repo.GetAsync<AccountEquipment>(filter: x => x.AccountId == accountId,
                    includes: source => source
                    .Include(ae => ae.AccountEquipmentFee).Include(ae => ae.CompanyEquipment).ThenInclude(ce => ce.Equipment));

                account.AccountPickVolumeDefaultAccount = await _repo.GetAsync<AccountPickVolumeDefault>(filter: x => x.AccountId == accountId,
                    includes: source => source
                    .Include(a => a.Equipment).Include(a => a.PartnerAccount));
            }
            else
            {
                 account = await _repo.GetByIdAsync<Account>(accountId);
            }

            if (account == null)
                throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Could not find Account with ID: {accountId}");

            return account;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

What I do not understand is, the controller returns `OK` status and all of my fields are populated.  However, the API hangs and does not return my data, in other words, the Swagger API (including front-end application) does not receive the response and keeps on showing the loading button.

I have a funny feeling it has something to do with `Serialization`, but not sure how to fix it.

I have made sure to turn off `SelfRefenceLooping`, as can be seen here:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(setup =>
        {
            setup.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            setup.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

Why is the API not returning the JSON object?

Comment: You say API hangs. So you doesn't receive 200 ok response on frontend-side, right? This means only that you front can't get response from server. Can't see any serialization problems. Try to call server-side API through REST API client like Postman and show results.

Comment: Swagger mimmics something like Postman, and even Swagger does not get response.  When I debug, I can see that the OK is returned, or atleast, the debugger steps over it

Comment: So... Do you receive **response** or not? You receive just empty 200 ok or API hangs and you can't get any response?

Comment: I do not receive any response

Comment: If that, you need to check your API accessible. You don't have serialization problem. There is accessible/blocking/deployment or smth problem. Try to check your API with different tool

Answer (score 0):

Can you try without the `.ConfigureAwait(false)`?

Except for that, you code seems ok and the API should work fine.

If you don't have it, I would recommend adding Swagger to your API, it's just a matter of 5-10 lines and it helps a lot in the development phase (and also avoid manual mistakes while testing). Here is the official documentation: [ASP.NET Core web API help pages with Swagger / OpenAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

You can also try to add a very dumb action in your controller, to try to identify where the issue comes from (Controller layer? Service layer? Facade layer?)

Comment: I am using swagger, stating that in my original question :-)

Comment: Oh sorry... Then can you try without ConfigureAwait?
I never used this method.

Comment: Could you post your startup file?

The order of the Add() and Use() is important and sometines issues come from that.